# How should I improve an answer to my own question?

Tags: discussion, answers, self-answer

Situation is as follows:

- I posted a question on Stack Exchange which, at the moment of the post, I did not know the answer to.
- Some answers were provided. One of them fits what I would define as good enough to be accepted.
- However, even though the answer I mentioned above is correct, it is not very pedagogic (i.e., requires a considerable amount of time to interpret it and realize it is indeed correct).

Now, I see some alternatives:

- Accept the answer mentioned above and be done with it.
- Edit the other user's answer, so as to make it pedagogical, include small details left aside.
- Post a new, improved answer to my own question, but mention that it comes from improving the other answer.

Since editing the answer to make it more pedagogical could require a considerable effort on my part, I think I would prefer the third alternative. Is there a general consensus over which course of action to take in these circumstances?

---

The actual question is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2590718/what-is-the-probability-distribution-of-the-points-obtained-by-player-a-in-this), and the answer I'm referring to is [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2590811/59345).

I have answered my own question in the more pedagogic way I mentioned. You can see my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2591913/59345) and compare with the original answer I obtained.

Comment: Upvote the answer you thought was good. Post another *community wiki* answer that gives credit to the other one and you can accept the CW answer.

Comment: Hi, just to make sure my answer is good, can we get the link to the actual post you mention ? I want to be sure I don't misinterpret your question

Comment: Sure, I'll edit my question to add this information.

Comment: I have now also added what I believe is a more pedagogic way of answering.

Comment: @JLagana Thanks, I now understand what you mean by the pedagogical's way , good answer by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you feel that an answer is incomplete and that you want to add your own original content, then you should not be editing the other answer.  You should be posting your own answer.  If you're creating a derived work of another person's answer then you of course need to cite the content that is there's.

Answer (score 1):

I would edit and accept after as it indeed answered you.

Iam not english speaking and often my answer are hard to read. The power of the community come from there, as if someone can edit me to be more clear I welcome that. Especially if the answer **actually** answer you.

*By editing it can be adding text to the answer, not a whole rewrite.*

Comment: But the question *isn't* asking about editing the question to make it clearer, it's suggesting editing it to add different information that wasn't there before

Comment: @Servy The answer took the OP time to interpret it, and was an answer afterall. Clear in that sense. To quote the OP; *i.e., requires a considerable amount of time to interpret it and realize it is indeed correct*

Comment: Yes, as a result of *it not having information that they feel was relevant*, not as a result of it being poorly phrased.  As such, they feel that the omitted information would be relevant to readers, not that the answer just needs to be rephrased, without changing the content of what it is saying.

Comment: @Servy I will ask the OP an example then, as I'am not sure, for me the phrasing in the question mean it's badly wrote, not in the correct wording, but it's an answer, not a case of missing information.

Comment: So you interpret them saying that they want to include details that weren't included as them meaning they don't want to add any new information, they just want to re-phrase the content already stated?  How do you come to that interpretation?

Comment: @Servy How you interpret that OP phrase? *•However, even though the answer I mentioned above is correct, it is not very pedagogic (i.e., requires a considerable amount of time to interpret it and realize it is indeed correct).* On my side I interpret it as such, It's missing nothing, as that answered him, but took time to understand

Comment: That the answer is correct, but has problems.  It doesn't state what those problems are.  Later on, when saying that they want to edit the answer to add in missing information, they have stated that what the previously unspecified problem was, was missing information.  Had they instead said that they want to edit the answer to phrase it more clearly, then that would be indicating that they felt it was unclear.

Comment: Why do you think that they'd say that they want to edit the answer to add missing information, if they had no intention of adding in any missing information to the answer and only intended to rephrase the existing content?